# jquery get the_permalink from a div and call it in script

Tags: jquery, wordpress

TL;DR
Hello, is there any way to get wordpress the_permalink on script something like echo and load it on jquery with working on all posts separately?

Long version:
Hello, In wordpress I'm trying to make my posts look like image thumbnail and when I hover over them it shows the title and category of the post. And how i'm doing that is when i hover the div that has image_thumb .show script runs. I want it to make like when i click on any place of the image it goes to the post link. and when i click on the category it goes to category. since i cannot use another link inside link. i made the imagethumb div go to links with ".click function" but i can't use  because java cant directly run php. So is there anyway i can get the correct link maybe like echoed somewhere and get the link and load it?

here's my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".select").hover(
                function(){         
                    $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(500);
                },          
                function(){
                    $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(500);
                }
            );
      $(".select").click(function(evt){
    window.location = '<?php the_permalink(); ?>';
});
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be more elegant solution, but a quick roundup is to use server-side code to export your required link as a "data-blablah" attribute of this div, then use jQuery to catch it.

For example, a link may look like `<a href="original/path" title="blah" class="select" data-permanlink="wanted/path">`

Then you can use jQuery to catch this attribute and header to it, something like this:

```
$(".select").click(function(evt){
    var newlink = this.attr('data-permanlink')
    window.location(newlink)
});
```

Comment: thanks :) i ended up making the site with no grid view so there is no need for it. but thanks :)

Comment: My pleasure. That's nice. Better to build something in convention :)